# Dialog with primefaces wizard when try to rewind to first page

Tags: primefaces

My environement:
primefaces 3.5
JSF 2.2

I have a wizard in a dialog panel that shows when I click a button. 
When I close dialog, and then open dialog once again, wizard isn`t rewind to first page.

I tried this :

```
<p:commandButton oncomplete="dialog.show()" update="dialogForm" ....... >
     <f:setPropertyActionListener value="start" target="#{bean.wizard.step}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

i get a  java.lang.IllegalStateException: the ID of the  component «frm02:start» alredy détected in the view.

Any ideas how to avoid that?

Comment: Idea: start by creating a [mcve]

Comment: tks I did all this, still have the same probleme I don't hunderstand why an unique id is detected twice in the view I have only one unique id

Answer (score 0):

I added `onHide` and `onShow` attributes to the `dialog`, so that the `wizard` always renders on the first tab (which in my example is `personal`)

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="addUser" header="Add User" appendTo="@(body)" closeOnEscape="true" dynamic="true" modal="true" onHide="PF('addUserWizard').loadStep('personal', true)"
        fitViewport="true" responsive="true" width="700px" height="400" resizable="false" onShow="PF('addUserWizard').loadStep('personal', true)">
<h:form>
    <p:wizard showStepStatus="false" showNavBar="false" widgetVar="addUserWizard" binding="#{wizard}">
        <p:tab id="personal" title="Personal">
        ...
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="confirm" title="Confirmation">
        ...
        </p:tab>
    </p:wizard>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Tks for the response! my probreme was that I'm using pf 3.5. I shoud have call it by Wizard.loadStep('step') in stad